# xcode/ios: When you import a file do you import everything that file imports?

Tags: xcode, import

Pretty basic questions but I can't confirm answer anywhere

1. When you import a file, say `TableController.h` that, in turn, imports another file, say, `DataObject.h`, do you automatically import that file too or do you need to import it separately?
2. When you import a file, do you also import any frameworks it has imported such as `#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>` or do you need to import core data again?

Thank you.